# Saving jwt token in react native

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage, react-native-keychain

```js
const response = await axios.post(`${config.END_POINT}/users`, formData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        })

        await Keychain.setGenericPassword('token', response.token)

/* App.js */

useEffect(() => {
        async function getToken() {
            try {
                const token = await Keychain.getGenericPassword()
                dispatch({
                    type: 'auth/setToken',
                    payload: token
                })
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.error(error.message)
            }
        }
        getToken()
    }, [dispatch])
```

I'm building my first react native app with expressJS and MongoDB and using jwt for authentication.

When I was working on ReactJS project, I used to store token in localstorage. But I don't have any idea about storing in React Native. I did research and found about `asyncStorage` and `react-native-keychain`. However, I got to know that `asyncStorage` is not secure.

So, I used `react-native-keychain` but it's having and error on both `setGenericPassword` and `getGenericPassword` :

```js
Cannot read property 'getGenericPasswordForOptions', 'setGenericPasswordForOptions' of null //Respectively
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [CryptoJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) to encrypt your token. And use [MMKV](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mmkv) to save it locally, apparently MMKV is 30x faster than AsyncStorage. Code example below:

```js
    import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
    import { MMKV } from 'react-native-mmkv';

    const storage = new MMKV();
    const secret = 'FAKE_SECRET';

    const encryptedToken = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('FAKE_TOKEN', 
    secret).toString();

    storage.set('userToken', encryptedToken);
```

It's not recommended to store the secretKey like this, maybe it's better to use [env vars](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-react-native-env-variables/).

To get and decrypt your token do this:

```js
    const encryptedToken = storage.getString('userToken');
    const decryptedBytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedToken, 
    secret);
    const userToken = decryptedBytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```